# org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Am trying to configure messageSource in Spring 4.x as below

My locale properties are in messages_xx.properties files

`messages_en_US.properties file`

```
error.title=error 
## format used for UI display of dates. see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
application.displayedDateFormat=M/d/yy
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateFormat=M/d/yy
## format used for UI display of date + time.
application.displayedDateTimeFormat=M/d/yy h:mm a
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateTimeFormat=M/d/yy h:mm a
```

`messages_zh_TW.properties file`

```
## format used for UI display of dates. see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
application.displayedDateFormat=yyyy/M/d
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateFormat=yyyy/M/d
## format used for UI display of date + time.
application.displayedDateTimeFormat=yyyy/M/d a h:mm
## format used by server. use only 2 digit year so app can parse both 2 and 4 digit years
application.dateTimeFormat=yyyy/M/d a h:mm
```

below is my admin-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="com.dc.core.common.UserSessionLocaleResolver"/>
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="UserLocale" />
</bean>
<bean id="core-messageSource"
    class="com.dc.core.spring.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
     <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.dc.core.spring.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="parentMessageSource">
        <ref bean="core-messageSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>application-messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="customJspViewResolver"
    class="com.dc.core.presentation.resolver.CustomJspViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/core/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="0" />
```

when the locale is changed spring is not able to find the message code as per the locale and am getting the below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'application.dateFormat' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.getMessage(MessageSourceAccessor.java:161)
    at com.dc.core.entity.binding.impl.EntityDataBinderRegistrar.getText(EntityDataBinderRegistrar.java:56)
    at com.dc.core.entity.binding.impl.EntityDataBinderRegistrar.setUpDateBinding(EntityDataBinderRegistrar.java:77)
    at com.dc.core.entity.binding.impl.EntityDataBinderRegistrar.registerCustomEditors(EntityDataBinderRegistrar.java:60)
    at com.dc.core.common.controller.impl.BaseMultiActionController.createBinder(BaseMultiActionController.java:494)
    at com.dc.core.common.controller.impl.BaseMultiActionController.bind(BaseMultiActionController.java:444)
```

Comment: Be sure you have the file `application-messages_en_US.properties` in the same level than `application-messages.properties`, it assuming `application.dateFormat` is defined in the `application-messages.properties` file and its variations

Comment: Actually my locales are in `messages_xx.properties` file all of my messages_xx.properties files are in src\main\resources

Comment: do you have the `messages_en_US.properties` file?

Comment: I checked the `DelegatingMessageSource` class getMessage(..)and in my scenario  `this.parentMessageSource` is null and throwing the exception but I dont understand why `this.parentMessageSource` is null in my case. `public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
  if (this.parentMessageSource != null) {
   return this.parentMessageSource.getMessage(code, args, locale);
  }
  else {
   throw new NoSuchMessageException(code, locale);
  }
 }`

Comment: Why not use only one `messageSource`? why is mandatory or required the hierarchy? I use the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`

Comment: Thats how our application is designed cant change it now, My application uses messages from both the messagesources

Comment: Ok I see, could you post the `CustomResourceBundleMessageSource` class? In XML the hierarchy is accomplish by the `parent` attribute. You are using a property, I need see the class.